# In minecraft, what is the recipe for a lead

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing in survival and I found a vein of iron. How do I make the iron bars into a lead?

[image]

May I have a minecraft recipe?

Comment: There's no such thing as lead in Minecraft. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you using a mod or are you referring to the [Lead](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Lead) item?

Comment: @DorianDore [There is](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Lead). What is also known as Leash is actually called a Lead. Though there is also a possibility of Erin meaning lead as a metal, since iron is mentioned.

Comment: @OrcJMR That's what I thought, since she had mentioned Iron.

Comment: @DorianDore I just assumed they meant the Leash, sense there was no Mods tag in the question, or anything implying that there were mods were in use.

Answer (score 6):

You need 4 string and 1 slimeball and apply them into the following Sequence...

[image]

[source: Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lead)

[source: Extra Click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)